# Accessing open files globally in Fortran

Tags: file-io, fortran, gfortran

Is there any means to accessing (reading, writing to) files that are opened in some other source code by just passing the unit number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is possible (for both reading and writing). Here is a short example:

```
module test_mod
contains

  subroutine myWrite( uFile )
    implicit none
    integer, intent(in) :: uFile

    write(uFile, *) 'Hello world'
  end subroutine
end module

program test
  use test_mod
  implicit none
  integer :: uFile, stat

  open(newunit=uFile, file='test.txt', status='replace', &
       action='write', iostat=stat)
  if(stat.ne.0) return

  call myWrite( uFile )
  close (uFile)
end program
```

---

```
$ cat test.txt 
 Hello world
```

Answer (score 1):

External file units are globally accessible.  You need not even pass the unit number, though that is a better practice than using hardcoded units.  This behavior defined in Fortran 2008 Cl. 9.5.1,

> **3** The external unit identified by a particular value of a *scalar-int-expr* is the same external unit in all program
>   units of the program.

where they provide this sample code in note 9.14:

> In the example:
>
> ```
> SUBROUTINE A
>    READ (6) X
>       ...
> SUBROUTINE B
>    N = 6
>    REWIND N
> ```
>
> the value 6 used in both program units identifies the same external unit.